# Any way to make setuptools exclude certain files when packaging up a distribution?

Tags: python, setuptools

I would prefer to not distribute my `tests.py` file in a django project that I'm distributing so that people who include the app won't need to run the tests. Is there any way to force setuptools to exclude certain files?